# PropertyChangedEventHandler null

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I have 2 `ObservableCollection<T>`s and each of the them has their `Card`s.

```cs
public class Card: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _CardTitle;
    public string CardTitle
    {
        get { return _CardTitle; }
        set 
        { 
            _CardTitle = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CardTitle");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Now when a `CardTitle` of the card is changed it is reflected on the UI thanks to `PropertyChangedEventHandler`.

But when I *move* a card from one collection to another and then *change* the `CardTitle`, I get `handler` as `null` thus, `PropertyChangedEventHandler` is not fired and I cannot see the change in UI.

I have scratched my head enough but cannot figure out why. If anyone has any idea then please help me before I get in trouble.

Comment: you might want to add the collections code along with adding/removing of an item.Also add the xaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "move"? You remove from first collection, and add to second yes? Does your datacontext implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

I tried to reproduce your code, but i didn't have any problem. Look, maybe you find some hints:

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
    this.DataContext = this;
}

private ObservableCollection<Card> _first;
public ObservableCollection<Card> First
{
    get { return _first; }
    set
    {
        _first = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("First");
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<Card> _second;
public ObservableCollection<Card> Second
{
    get { return _second; }
    set
    {
        _second = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Second");
    }
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    //Init collections
}

private void ChangeItemName(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var card = (sender as Button).DataContext as Card;
    card.CardTitle = ":)";
}

private void ChangeCollection(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var card = (sender as Button).DataContext as Card;
    First.Remove(card);
    Second.Add(card);
    card.CardTitle = "xD";
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<StackPanel>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding First}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CardTitle}" />
                        <Button Content="Change name" Click="ChangeItemName" />
                        <Button Content="Change collection" Click="ChangeCollection" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Second}" Grid.Column="1">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CardTitle}" />
                        <Button Content="Change name" Click="ChangeItemName" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```